# Lodash - Using _.update inside _.forEach

Tags: scope, lodash

I'm trying to use the `_.update` method inside of the `_.forEach` method and I'm not understanding why the newly added property has a value of `undefined`.

FYI, I have to have the function defined separately and then pass it to the `_.update` method, I can't write it directly into the `_.update` method (it must be dynamic).

I've tried structuring this in multiple different ways, but none of them work.

```js
let object = [{ 'a': 1, 'b': 1 }, { 'a':1, 'b': 1 }]
function myFunc (row) { return row.a + row.b }
_.forEach(object, row => _.update(row, 'c', myFunc(row)))

console.log(object)
```

I expected to get:

```js
[{ 'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 2 }, { 'a':1, 'b': 1, 'c': 2  }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`_.update()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#update) method is used for updating an existing property, and it accepts an updater function, and not a value (like the one generated by myFunc).

In your case you should use [`_.set()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#set), that accepts a value:

```js
const object = [{ 'a': 1, 'b': 1 }, { 'a':1, 'b': 1 }]

function myFunc(row) {
  return row.a + row.b
}

_.forEach(object, row => _.set(row, 'c', myFunc(row)))

console.log(object)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

And if you don't have to use lodash, you can use `Array.forEach()`:

```js
const object = [{ 'a': 1, 'b': 1 }, { 'a':1, 'b': 1 }]

object.forEach(row => row.c = myFunc(row))

function myFunc(row) {
  return row.a + row.b
}

console.log(object)
```